# Is it possible to create a list in WSS 3.0 based on a custom template using SharePoint web services?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to create a SharePoint list using SharePoint web services (instance is SharePoint Services v3.0). That list should be built from the custom list template that I have created previously. Browsing through MSDN documentation resulted in the following resolutions:

```
services.ListsService.AddList(title, description, templateID);
```

or

```
services.ListsService.AddListFromFeature(title, description, featureGUID, templateID);
```

Now, if we take a look at the first implementation, there is a problem as the templateID doesn't exist for my custom template - it refers to the default ones instead.

The second implementation is no good either as I need the templateID again, but I also need the feature GUID which I have no idea how to get. Could anyone help please? Thanks.

Comment: How about in sharepoint 2010, have they fixed it there yet?

Comment: No, they haven't. Actually, I think that SP dev team has abandoned the concept of web services in SharePoint, more or less. Instead, the 2010 version introduces the SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model which is a dramatic leap forward when it comes to the development of apps that interact with SharePoint but are not executed on the SP server machines. Check it out: http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/SharePoint2010Developer/ClientObjectModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been confirmed to me from people from Microsoft that, unfortunately, it is not possible to utilize features to create a SharePoint list using SharePoint web services. It can be either done by developing custom web service, or by using Object Model.